# How can I reverse individual words in a string while using a stack?

Tags: java, string, stack, reverse

I am new to programming and I'm taking a beginner level programming class. I've tried looking around for my answer and I've found results that may work, but I don't understand how to implement them while using a stack. I'm attempting to reverse a string's individual words without reversing the entire string.

For example: the user inputs the sentence "Pies are great!" and I need the output to be "seiP era !taerg"

So far I've managed to write a program that will reverse a string in its entirety, so the output using the above example is: "!taerg era seiP" As you can see, I want to reverse the words themselves without reversing the order of the words, but I must take input using a stack.

The following is what I have so far:

```
public class ReversedString{

private static  ArrayStack<String> stack;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    stack = new ArrayStack<String>();
    String string = "";
    String stringReversed = "";

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the string that you want to reverse: ");
    string = scanner.nextLine();
    string.split(" ");

    for(int i=0; i<string.length(); i++){
        stack.push(string.substring(i, i+1));
    }   

    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        stringReversed += stack.pop();
    }

    System.out.println("The reverse of the string is: " + stringReversed);
```

Comment: If you are able to reverse the string whats the problem with words?

Comment: I don't understand how to utilize a stack to push in a string and pop out the individual reversed words.

Comment: Instead of complete string push individual words and do the same untill the whole string is processed.

Answer (score 1):

```
read character
while character is whitespace
    // do nothing to skip multiple whitespaces.
    read character

while character is not whitespace
    push character onto stack
    read character

// Just read a word, so now dump it back out.
while stack is not empty
    ch = pop stack
    print ch
```

Obviously this needs to be in a loop to do multiple words.

Sample implementation of `read character`

```
int index = 0;
String theString = "Pies are great!"

char readCharacter()
{
    // TODO: needs error checking so you don't run off the end of the string.
    char ch = theString.charAt(index);
    index++;
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: This looks the most promising, but how can I read the characters in a string exactly?

Comment: If you already have the string, you can use `charAt` and just increment the index. I'll edit to give a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Split the sentence with white-space(`" "`) like `String#split` you will get the splitted string which will be words ("Pies", "are", "great!") and then push that into stack and pop the value individually.

```
String str ="Pies are great!";
String[] strs = str.split(" "); // "Pies", "are", "great!"
String newStr = "";
for(String str1:strs){
   //push str1
   // pop str1 and add it to newStr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("Pies are great!");
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(new StringBuilder(sc.next()).reverse() + " ");
    }
```

output

```
seiP era !taerg
```

or with java.util.Stack

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("Pies are great!");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();
        for (char c : sc.next().toCharArray()) {
            st.push(c);
        }
        while (!st.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(st.pop());
        }
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    System.out.print(sb);
```

output

```
seiP era !taerg
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, but unfortunately we haven't discussed StringBuilder in class and I have no idea of how it works. Is there a way to do this without using StringBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Take the code you've already written to reverse a whole String using a stack, and convert it into its own method.  Your stack is useful for retrieving letters in reverse order (Last In First Out).  Something like:

```
public String reverse(String str) {
  . . .
}
```

In your main method, split your String into multiple words, and pass each word to your reverse method iteratively.  Don't use a stack for your words.  Your words are FIFO, and a stack provides LIFO.